# Permission denied while writing a systemfile on android

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-source, hdmi, runtime-permissions

I was trying to write to `/sys/class/switch/hdmi/state` but i got permission denied error.

```
# echo 0 > /sys/class/switch/hdmi/state                                 
/system/bin/sh: can't create /sys/class/switch/hdmi/state: Permission denied
```

I searched online and found the below answer.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**My question is, where do i set this permission? If android_manifest.xml, then which one? there are a lot of android_manifest files.**

Comment: To your main app manifest not to any library if you are using. One more thing one app have only one manifest file until unless you use any library

Comment: @AadeshMishra: But I'm not using any app. I just wanted to see if my HDMI will get turned off if i gave ```/sys/class/switch/hdmi/state``` 0.

Comment: If you use `adb shell` to execute this command, maybe you should execute `adb root` before you enter `adb shell` to execute the above command.